# SharePoint Custom List - Items Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, item-level-permissions

This might be slightly open questions so apologies in advance.  I wanted to check if anyone is using 'folder' in the custom list to break inheritance in groups rather than individual items.

I have a list where we have to grant permissions to  departments on the multiple items and I wanted to avoid grant permission individually.

I know I could use MS Flow to break permissions through the HTTP connector but not sure if there is a best to do achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have used folders to manage permissions for sets of items in the past. The goal is to break inheritance in as few places as possible to minimize the effort required should the permission strategy ever need to change.

Another benefit of folders is that you don't have to worry about using Flow or some other technology to set permissions on new items. They automatically inherit the permissions of the folder in which they are contained.

So you create the list, add the folders, set permissions on the folders, and you are good to go. You also might want to create some views that show all items regardless of the folder in which they are contained. These are generally known as "flattened" views.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I have used it in the past precisely for the same reasons.  I was told that it is a heck and I shouldn't be doing this, but very happy to hear that it is used by others.  I suppose It is now more important when Flow HTTP connector is premium.